# finding the names that contains letters 'psy' and setting default values in outer join in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am stuck with the two problems.

1 - how to find or extract all the departments that contains letters 'psy'

so far i used this

```
select dept_name
from department
where dept_name like '%P%';
```

which gives me result - 'Physics' which is not correct.

and my department list is like this

```
  "Biology"
  "Comp. Sci."
  "Elec. Eng."
  "Finance"
  "History"
  "Music"
  "Physics"
```

2 - my second question is

I wrote a query that gives me instructor name, instructor id from instructor table and section id from teaches table. I used outer join to get the required result but i left with few blank spaces where i want to put the default value '0'
How can i do that?

my query

```
  select instructor.id,instructor.name,teaches.sec_id
  from instructor 
  full outer join teaches
  on instructor.id = teaches.id;
```

from 'kim' rest of the rows has not secid where i want to put 0
my result

```
id      name       secid
"76766";"Crick";   "1"
"76766";"Crick";   "1"
"83821";"Brandt";   "1"
"83821";"Brandt";  "2"
"83821";"Brandt";  2"
"98345";"Kim";     "1"
"33456";"Gold";    
"58583";"Califieri";""
76543";"Singh";     ""
```

instructor table

```
id       name         department
"10101"; "Srinivasan";"Comp. Sci."
"12121"; "Wu";        "Finance"
"15151" ;"Mozart";    "Music"
"22222"; "Einstein";  "Physics"
```

takes table

```
id       subject  section
"00128"; "CS-101"; "1"
"00128"; "CS-347"; "1"
"12345"; "CS-101"; "1"
"12345"; "CS-190"; "2"
"12345"; "CS-315"; "1"
"12345"; "CS-347"; "1"
```

since data is too large i couldn't put whole table here but its enough to give idea.

Comment: First question depends a little on your desired results.  Either use `or` with multiple checks or just use `like '%psy%'`.  Second question, look at using `coalesce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `'%Psy%'` in your `like` instead of just `'%P%'`.  If you want just those that start with `Psy`, then you want `'Psy%'`
2. Use COALESCE : `COALESCE(teaches.sec_id, 0) AS sec_id` in your SELECT statement.